# Python GUI toolkits that support text widget transparency or text widget with canvas background?

Tags: python, user-interface, text, canvas

I am trying to write a program that displays a scrollable text widget over a striped background. The width of the stripes, the spacing between stripes, and the color of the stripes can be set by the user.

Here is a quick and dirty example of what I'm imagining:

[image: Example]

(It might seem like an ugly and pointless program, but it would be useful as a therapy tool for certain kinds of eye problems)

My original idea was to draw the stripes as rectangles on a canvas widget. Then I planned on overlaying the canvas with a text widget with a transparent background.

Right now, I am using Tkinter. But it appears that the text widget in Tkinter doesn't support transparency or using a canvas as a background. It appears that only a solid color can be used as a background.

What GUI toolkits are available for Python that would support the use of text widget background transparency / or a text widget that uses a canvas as a background?

Comment: I believe gtk3 can do this and perhaps gtk2. You might be looking for something more along the lines of pygame or pyglet

Comment: I thought about using pyglet, but GUI toolkits for pyglet are almost non-existent or haven't been updated in the last 5 years. I'll check out gtk, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use Tkinter, here is a short example using the canvas widget.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=800, height=500)
        canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        for i in range(0, 800, 40):
            i+= 40
            fill = "yellow" if (i / 40) % 2 == 0 else "green"
            canvas.create_rectangle(i, 0, i+20, 500, fill=fill, outline="")
        canvas_id = canvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw")
        canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="this is the text "*300, width=780)
        canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, font=("courier", 12))
        canvas.insert(canvas_id, 12, "new ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot of working example]

Adding scrolling is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked great and I got it to scroll and resize nicely. But then... I loaded a string the length of an entire book (the Wonderful Wizard of Oz) and it made the canvas start acting funny and freeze during scrolling. I'm not sure if the canvas can handle as much text as a want to put in it...

Comment: Update - I solved the above problem by implementing pages. Only a set amount of text is on the canvas at a time, and it's working great again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WXpython](http://www.wxpython.org/)

here is an example of a transparent top-level window

[Transparent Frames](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames)

WX is the only GUI library that i think could do this tkinter is good for more basic GUI's while WX is much more flexible

here are a few more examples of using transparency with WX

[Transparent StaticText](http://www.keacher.com/994/transparent-static-text-in-wxpython/)

[Transparent Panel](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/transparent-background-for-a-panel-widget-td2362723.html)

I hope this helps you out!