# Set Inputfield to have a transparent background

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, transparency

I've got a problem.
I want to realize an Inputfield ( Text() ) in front of an image ( ImageTk.Photoimage() )
But the white background of the Inputfield covers the image. So my Question is, how can i set the background of Text() to full transparency?

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = 'C:/Users/David/Pictures/5.png'

root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
Text(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Common guys answer pls...

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. I have deleted your other question, you should create a separate post for it.

Answer (score 0):

### Make a Text widget at full width of the parent window ( and remain that )

```
Text(root).pack( side   = "BOTTOM", fill ="X", expand = 1 )
```

or

```
Text(root).grid( sticky = W+S+E )
```

---

### Make a Text widget have a transparent background

Ref. >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479446/3666197

Answer (score -1):

to make a transparent background:
if you pack your image into a canvas widget then you can post text over the top of it using

```
canvas.create_text()
```

a good reference for the canvas widget can be found here:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

to control how wide the widget packs itself
If you are using pack you could use either:

```
Text.pack(fill="x")
```

or:

```
Text.pack(fill="x", expand=True) 
# this one would also make it expand if you resize the window
```

or if you use grid:

```
Text.grid(sticky="nesw")
```

and to make it expand if you resize window:

```
parent.grid_columnconfigure(columnnumber, weight=1)
```

if you use grids you can change the relative rate at which your widgets expand by changing the weight of that row/column

James

Comment: This is not what he is asking.

Comment: at the bottom he asks: And i got another Question (Sorry, Im quite new at Python) How can i set the Text () at the full width of the window?

Comment: Yes but he shouldn't - one post should only have one question. Otherwise you'll get a ton of partial answers. The question to be answered is the one in the title.