# How do I insert text over a visible background using tkinter?

Tags: python

How do I insert text over canvas without blocking out the image background? I know this is a newbie question, but I can't find the answer.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor=NW)

canvas.create_text(2, 2, text="Python")

mainloop()
```

edit: look like I finally figured it out (thanks @Jasper).

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

master = Tk()

#width, height = Image.open(image.png).size

canvas = Canvas(master, width=900, height=563)
canvas.pack()

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor=NW)

canvas_id = canvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw")
canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="this is the text "*300, width=780)
canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, font=("courier", 12))
canvas.insert(canvas_id, 12, "new ")

#canvas.create_text(2, 2, text="Python")

mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479038/python-gui-toolkits-that-support-text-widget-transparency-or-text-widget-with-ca something you are looking for?

Comment: @the_prole You should post the solution as an answer rather than editing your question. If you do not do so, StackOverflow system may automatically delete your question, preventing anyone with the same issue than you from finding your question and answer. :o